# How can this SQL statement throw the following exception?

Tags: sql, exception, foreign-keys

how can this statement:

```
DELETE FROM passage
WHERE passageid NOT IN
(
    SELECT passageid from PreEndedPassages_passages
    UNION SELECT fromPassageid from severalvisit
    UNION SELECT toPassageid from severalvisit
    UNION SELECT registerPassageid from stationobjects WHERE registerpassageid IS NOT NULL
    UNION SELECT beginPassageid from stationobjects WHERE beginPassageid IS NOT NULL
    UNION SELECT endPassageid from stationobjects WHERE endPassageid IS NOT NULL
)
```

throw this exception?

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_statobj_begpasid". The conflict occurred in database "db.mdf", table "dbo.stationobjects", column 'beginpassageid'.
```

I have no clue, but it happened. beginPassageId is a foreign key on passageid.

EDIT:
Consider the NOT IN. I want to delete all passages that don't exist in one of its related tables. It usually works, but it happened once.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the relation is between passage(passageid) and stationobjects(beginPassageid).Because your query is right no problem it must delete if the relation you specified is right

Comment: Yes sure. Otherwise it wouldn't throw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

It means passage is parent table. and stationobjects is child table. You are trying to remove passageid from passage table which is present in stationobjects table as well.

First try to remove those passageid from stationobjects and then you can run this delete statement.

Alternate approach is cascade delete, if your DB supports that.

Comment: hmm, i'm trying to delete all passages without any relation to one of its child tables (NOT IN), so it should not throw this exception at all. It usually works, but I got it once..

Answer (score 0):

this kind of occur when you have a foreign key relationship in the two table.
This violates the Refrential Integrity .
so if you delete record from the primary table and record exist in foreign key table,
then you have two options:
1. either set the delete rule to cascade so that when ever you delete primary record the foreign key table record will get automatically deleted.
2.delete record from foreign key table first then from primary key table.

Comment: Please consider the NOT IN. It should not throw the exception.

Answer (score -1):

These kind of errors come up when table A foreign key is table B primary key and when you try to delete record in table A that has linking in table B, then deletion will not happen. Try dropping foreign key relation before delete. Same way truncate is used in tables by dropping fk relations and rebuilding them again after the table is reset

Comment: Foreign key relation is there for a reason .... it's way to bad idea to drop it just like that, what if he a stored procedure or a view that does join via that table or something?

Comment: Consider the NOT IN. It should not throw the exception at all.